# Error while installing cloudera manager yum install cloudera-manager-agent

Tags: cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

Error while installing cloudera manager yum install cloudera-manager-agent
I'm installing cloudera manager 5.5, but getting below exception.

Thanks in advance.

below is the exception details.

```
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cloudera-manager-agent.x86_64 0:5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: fuse for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mod_ssl for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: MySQL-python for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: fuse-libs for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: cyrus-sasl-gssapi for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python-psycopg2 for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-devel for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /lib/lsb/init-functions for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cloudera-manager-agent.x86_64 0:5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mod_ssl for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: MySQL-python for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python-psycopg2 for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-devel for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /lib/lsb/init-functions for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
---> Package cyrus-sasl-gssapi.x86_64 0:2.1.23-15.el6_6.2 will be installed
---> Package fuse.x86_64 0:2.8.3-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package fuse-libs.x86_64 0:2.8.3-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package libxslt.x86_64 0:1.1.26-2.el6_3.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /lib/lsb/init-functions for package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64 (cloudera-manager)
           Requires: MySQL-python
Error: Package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64 (cloudera-manager)
           Requires: /lib/lsb/init-functions
Error: Package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64 (cloudera-manager)
           Requires: httpd
Error: Package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64 (cloudera-manager)
           Requires: mod_ssl
Error: Package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64 (cloudera-manager)
           Requires: python-psycopg2
Error: Package: cloudera-manager-agent-5.5.1-1.cm551.p0.8.el6.x86_64 (cloudera-manager)
           Requires: openssl-devel
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Installing check prerequisite steps.

1. which version of linux Cent 6.5 lacter (python2.6 is default)
2. Before installing install

   ```
   yum -y install ntpd openssh openssh-client oralejdk17
   ```

please check below more info:
http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/manager/5-1-x/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cm5ig_install_path_A.html#cmig_topic_6_5_1_unique_1

Answer (score 2):

First check these dependencies:

- MySQL-python
- httpd
- mod_ssl
- python-psycopg2
- openssl-devel

Try to install these packages first to see if they were causing the issue.

(Search for the packages with

```
yum search {package}
```

and if you can't find them, install the repository suggested by Ripunjay Godhani).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a general repository that has those packages available. If you believe you do, look in the /etc/yum.repos.d/.repo and make sure they are not Enabled=0. If so, you can do:

yum --enablerepo=* install cloudera-manager-agent

And that will enable all disabled to pull packages, or you can --enablerepo= and just enabled that specific one.

Answer (score 1):

configure the needed epel repo based on your OS

https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/

`wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum clean all
yum repolist`

after above steps retry your installation

Answer (score 0):

To install cloudera manager server or agent you need to install related dependencies also or if you are connected to internet it will directly download from internet. If you don't have internet download those dependency packages and create local repos then clean and update repos then try to reinstall again